# Print \r correctly in console

Tags: python, eclipse, printing, pydev

When I write a script that updates a printed line, for example like this:

```
for i in range(101):
    print(str(i) + "% \r", end="")
```

and run this script using the terminal (Ubuntu), I get the correct output, that updated the line:

```
100%
```

However, using Pydev in Eclipse, the Eclipse console does this:

```
0%
1%
2%
...
100%
```

Anyone know how to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be the old CR LF problem. Depending on the OS and the console you are using, CR and LF as a line termination will be interpreted differently.

Some systems require a CRLF as an end of line.
Some systems only require LF but do the CR implicitly.
Some systems (like yours) do a LF before each CR implicitly, although this is the first time I see this.

Maybe there is a way to edit the newline settings for your PyDev console.

EDIT: Or you might use ANSI escape codes for moving the cursor around. Like CSInD for n characters to the left or CSInC for n characters to the right.

Comment: Seems to me too like CR LF problematic, though it is strange. As you said, some systems only require LF but do the CR implicitly. What I see here though is CR with LF implicitly done, which IMHO is just plain wrong, I also have never seen this before. Anyway - I'm looking for that way to edit newline settings for my console, but can't seem to find any. Maybe I'm blind, but I'm afraid they don't exist :(

Comment: Really strange behaviour. But with ANSI esc codes you should be on the safe side anywhere.

Comment: Just tried ANSI codes, same story there... works as intended if run in terminal, but the console in eclipse just prints a block for the code. Seems to be a general problem and I'm starting to doubt that there's a fix for that =/

Comment: Just to note, this is the console provided by Eclipse itself and this support should have to be fixed there... ( i.e.: create a feature request at http://bugs.eclipse.org )

Answer (score 3):

This is because 'print' always generates a new line whenever you use \r or not, try sys.stdout instead:

```
import time, sys

for i in range(101):
    sys.stdout.write(str(i) + "% \r")
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(.3)
```

Comment: Doesn't change the print behaviour for Eclipse 4.6.3 PyDev console under Python 3.5.2