# How to flush with aptana?

Tags: python, aptana, flush

sys.stdout.flush() doesn't work with aptana.
I've tried :

```
import sys
import time
for count in range(100) :
   sys.stdout.write("\r"   str(count) + "%") 
   sys.stdout.flush()
   time.sleep(1)
```

The flush doesn't work with aptana.
I have something like :

```
1%
2%
3%
....
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with flushing, but printing '\r' to the console. Aptana uses PyDev and PyDev's terminal is not a real one. There are [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10520200/pydev-send-stdout-to-a-real-tty-terminal) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6125692/print-r-correctly-in-console) on SO dealing with PyDev's console. Seems like the PyDev's console was not meant to handle this. Your best bet would be to try this out on a real console.